# I embedded this html button on my website but it doesn't work

Tags: html, web, click

What could be the possible reasons?

```html
<!-- # # Code # # -->
<div class="link-item-wrapper">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/thestackoverflow/" >
<img src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/666282be8229.png" >
</div>
<!-- # # # # # # # -->
```

**Observations:**

1. Button is clickable but does nothing...
2. Middle Mouse button works and opens the website correctly.
3. hovering the mouse shows the website correctly in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me in firefox, but you should explicitely close the `a` tag after the `img`.

```
<div class="link-item-wrapper">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/thestackoverflow/">
<img src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/666282be8229.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I used chrome for the same it works when I am testing with _live server plugin_ in VSC and it works, but when I upload the same code to website it doesn't do anything, is this some kind of glitch? 

Comment: This sounds like a glitch to me, I'm not sure what would cause that. Sounds to me like an issue elsewhere in the code, though.

Comment: looks like it's issue elsewhere in the code code I tried on firefox same result, need to recheck. Thanks for the help